# What is the solublity of water in liquid carbon dioxide at low temperature?

Tags: water, solubility, reference-request

The solubility of water in liquid carbon dioxide has been investigated by Hosmer W. Stone in 1943 from 
-29 to about 22 °C.

Is there any research done on the solubility of water in liquid $\ce{CO2}$ at still lower temperatures ?

Answer (score -1):

The lower the temperature and higher the pressure, the more soluble CO2 is in water.  Pepsi and Coke have staudiesd this for years.

Comment: You have it backwards. The OP wanted solubility of water in liquid CO2 and actual data, not just a generalization.